# Keyboard navigation with react-select don't work inside of sweetalert2 (sweetalert2-react-content)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, sweetalert2

I try to implement a react-select: and all works fine. It's amazing:

```
                        <Select
                            value={this.state.selectedCourse}
                            onChange={this.handleCourseChange}
                            options={courses.map((course) => {
                                return ({value: course.id, label: course.name});
                            })}
                            className={'react-selectize-custom'}
                            theme={theme => ({
                                ...theme,
                                borderRadius: 0,
                                colors: {
                                    ...theme.colors,
                                    primary25: '#f7f7f7',
                                    primary: '#2679ab',
                                },
                            })}
                            isClearable
                            isSearchable
                        />
```

[image]

All works fine BUT I can not navigate with the keyboard. Not at all.

Has this something to do with the state (this.state.selectedCourse) but when this is a problem, 
why navigation with mouse works?

Can someone help?

I created a Codesandbox:

[Codesandbox - Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bash-hu24h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hi Slowwie, could you provide the entire code with your `this. handleCourseChange` function or create an example in codesandbox please ?

Comment: Thank u for reply! I created a example in codesandbox - and I was surprised (it worked) - but in my project it does not work. 
I realized that the problem only occours inside of a sweetalert2 component.
Hope u can help me a bit in the right direction to solve the problem.